# Passing variables to extended template

Tags: html, django

I'm having templates that later my all other templates extend.

Most basic template is base.html. It includes the navigation bar:
`{% include 'includes/navigation.html' %}`

Navigation bar should display different titles depending on the role set:

```
    {% if role == "admin" %}
        <p class="title">Welcome to the Administrator Dashboard!</p>
    {% elif role == "user" %}
        <p class="title">Welcome to your Dashboard!</p>
    {% endif %}
```

From base.html a few other layouts extend, for example 2_column.html

```
{% extends "layouts/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
        <div class="block block_main col-md-9">
            {% block block_main %}{% endblock block_main %}
        </div>
        <div class="block block_side col-md-3">
            {% block block_side %}{% endblock block_side %}
        </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

And only from these templates I build all my other html files. For example login.html:

```
{% extends "layouts/2_column.html"%}

{% block block_main %}
    <h3 class="block_title">Login</h3>
    <form method="post">

        <!-- Form -->
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="file_id">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username">
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock block_main %}
```

I cannot figure out how to pass the role correctly all the way up to the navigation.html. Is that even possible? I've tried to wrap up the whole template in:

{% with role="admin" %}
{% endwith %}

but if {% extends ... %} is inside it tells me that the `with` tag is undefined.

I've tried to pass variable with extends: `{% extends "layouts/2_column.html" with role="publisher" %}` but `extends takes only one argument`.

I know I could pass the variable in the view.py in the render_template method but is there a way to do this from the template layer - it really is the template responsibility to draw the correct title?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter what html includes/extends what. You can and should pass that information in `views`. You can do it in the class based view or the method one. Example:

```
class YourView(DjangoView):
    ...
    extra_content = {'role_admin': True if user.is_superuser else False}
    ...
```

Then in html:

```
{% if role_admin %}
    <p class="title">Welcome to the Administrator Dashboard!</p>
{% else %}
    <p class="title">Welcome to your Dashboard!</p>
{% endif %}
```